# WebGL build is not working(build error located below), I am coding a C# game a I need to get it online through a link. What do I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00275] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I have tried building in windows and the build works but C# is not compatible so the game won't run.
I have tried building it in different places and tried building it in the folder with all the game files.
I have no idea what to do, anyone have an idea?
Edited error: This is now the correct error.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong error I will post a new one right now

Comment: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00275] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <9ba1187881a84a08b5f9c4cb333d7a6a>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Sorry, that's the correct error I was testing something.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, try going into Your Project/ Library/ and delete every folder with the word Cache in it. Also try Exporting directly to a new folder in Desktop or your C:// drive.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem and applied almost every possible solution but never solved .. but finally one thing that solved my problem was . you gotta keep trying to build it to different LocalDisks each time . and if i explain you what i wanna say is (I have 3 partitions of Local disks i.e(Local disk E, Local Disk F, Local disk G) my project was in E so first time i encountered this error i went to google and applied every possible solution regarding to this problem and then youtube and then unity answers Bla bla bla ... took me 2 days but nothing worked Finally i decided to change my build location eg.from Local disk E to F but not worked and then i again changed my build location from F to Local Disk G and Boom it worked without any error!)
You just need to change your build location. from one local disk to other and it will work at specific local disk Hope it will work :).